# How do I reliably get onmousedown or onclick events from a div that contains embeded Unity WebPlayer

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

In Chrome for OSX the event is fired, in Chrome Win8 it is not.  Is there a way to get this click?  Actually for Chrome Win8 I don't get ANY click or onmousedown events.  Even when I set:

```
document.onmousedown=function(){...}
```

if the mousedown is performed over the webplayer, no event fires.  I would like a javascript user initiated event to fire when a user clicks on the webplayer.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Keep in mind that the Unity Web Player will consume the click.  I don't know if there's a way to propagate that down.

Why not do the same functionality in Unity and have it fire off Javascript?  Unity can detect the click, flag that it's now in focus, and do `Application.Eval()` on any javascript you need.

Comment: Once you allow Unity run the javascript via Application.ExternalEval()  or Application.ExternalCall(), you lose the "user initiated" aspect of the event.  Therefore, a window.open() will pop-up a new new window, or be blocked by the browser, as opposed to open a new tab.

Comment: Yup, so if you want a user initiated click, you need dom elements that aren't overlapping with the web player.